# where can I find build files in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, c, eclipse

Im using eclipse to build a android application (java and c code)

where can I find (1) ant file and (2) c build file

auto generated in eclipse?

They are called `ant` and `build.xml` ?

I want to take them and edit a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your eclipse workspace directory and run the following command -

> find . -name build.xml 
>   find . -name ant

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and type `build.xml`, this will take you directly to the ant build script in the IDE.